# DAX : color data, based on value

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dax, ssas-tabular

I am looking for a way to color my data value using coding. Say for -ve value red color and +ve value green color. Is there any formatting dax function or any other way so that visually it would be easy for end user of pivot table. Note I would not like to go for conditional formatting in excel. My end user need not do any steps in excel itself.  thanks

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. DAX ("data analysis expressions") is a data processing engine and in your case Excel is the visualisation layer. Things like color coding etc. can only be done in the later.

Comment: MDX provides it [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145573.aspx). I am looking for similar thing for DAX a.k.a. SSSA tabular.

Answer (score 0):

DAX functions have no way to do excel cell formatting/color. It is a requested functionality on microsoft site for DAX. thanks